# How to print dictionary values by key name?

Tags: python

I know I'm missing something simple here, but need help.

I have a `dict_values` that look like this:

```
dict_values = [
[{'index': 0,
   'codec_name': 'h264',
   'codec_long_name': 'H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10',
   'profile': 'High',
   'duration': '33.400000',
   'bit_rate': '310702',
   'bits_per_raw_sample': '8',
   'nb_frames': '835',
   'disposition': {'default': 1,
                   'dub': 0,
                   'original': 0,
                   'comment': 0,
                   'lyrics': 0,
                   'karaoke': 0,
                   'forced': 0,
                   'hearing_impaired': 0,
                   'visual_impaired': 0,
                   'clean_effects': 0,
                   'attached_pic': 0,
                   'timed_thumbnails': 0},
   'tags': {'language': 'und', 'handler_name': 'VideoHandler'}}],
 {'filename': '/data/videoblocks-friends-gathering-in-campsite-around-bonfire-and-watching-movie-with-projector-on-van-side-in-dark-evening_hxdsarymm__e5cc36f7ec4f7b2cb6729b2f9a807d98__P360.mp4',
  'nb_streams': 1,
  'nb_programs': 0,
  'format_name': 'mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2',
  'format_long_name': 'QuickTime / MOV',
  'start_time': '0.000000',
  'duration': '33.400000',
  'size': '1308060',
  'bit_rate': '313307',
  'probe_score': 100,
  'tags': {'major_brand': 'isom',
           'minor_version': '512',
           'compatible_brands': 'isomiso2avc1mp41',
           'encoder': 'Lavf58.29.100'}},
 0,
 33.4,
 'h264',
 'H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10',
 640,
 360,
 'yuv420p',
 '640x360 @ yuv420p',
 25.0,
 '25/1',
 {}]
```

When brought into a list I can't seem to address them.  It does seem there are multiple dictionaries here or something.  How would I address the field by its name? I have tried multiple ways and am not able to get to "duration" in my dict_value when converted to a list.

```
dict = *all the values above*
print(dict.get('duration'))
```

Any ideas on how I can call these fields by their key name?

Comment: You should not use `dict_values` this way. Just use the original dict from which you got that `dict_values` object

Comment: I am using the original dict that I got the dict_values from -- maybe not a good way to formulate my question as I was just making an example of it.

Comment: @superbrain that is how the dict_value is listed, so I wanted to show how it is listed.

I am just trying to figure out how to address dict_values that have multiple nested dictionaries.

Comment: @superbrain better?

Comment: Hmm, barely. Still a messy blob. I'd use `pprint.pp`. And better on the original `dict`, as DeepSpace said.

Comment: You aren't working with a dict, but a list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No it's not a list, only martineau's edit made it look that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
data=[[{'index': 0, 'codec_name': 'h264', 'codec_long_name': 'H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10', 'profile': 'High', 'duration': '33.400000', 'bit_rate': '310702', 'bits_per_raw_sample': '8', 'nb_frames': '835', 'disposition': {'default': 1, 'dub': 0, 'original': 0, 'comment': 0, 'lyrics': 0, 'karaoke': 0, 'forced': 0, 'hearing_impaired': 0, 'visual_impaired': 0, 'clean_effects': 0, 'attached_pic': 0, 'timed_thumbnails': 0}, 'tags': {'language': 'und', 'handler_name': 'VideoHandler'}}], {'filename': '/data/videoblocks-friends-gathering-in-campsite-around-bonfire-and-watching-movie-with-projector-on-van-side-in-dark-evening_hxdsarymm__e5cc36f7ec4f7b2cb6729b2f9a807d98__P360.mp4', 'nb_streams': 1, 'nb_programs': 0, 'format_name': 'mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2', 'format_long_name': 'QuickTime / MOV', 'start_time': '0.000000', 'duration': '33.400000', 'size': '1308060', 'bit_rate': '313307', 'probe_score': 100, 'tags': {'major_brand': 'isom', 'minor_version': '512', 'compatible_brands': 'isomiso2avc1mp41', 'encoder': 'Lavf58.29.100'}}, 0, 33.4, 'h264', 'H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10', 640, 360, 'yuv420p', '640x360 @ yuv420p', 25.0, '25/1', {}]
print(data[0][0].get('duration'))
```

Comment: That's it! Can you explain how you found to use the two "[0]"? I can't seem to figure out how to address complex dictionaries like this.

Comment: because your dict is inner two array

Comment: @DerekEdwards **it's not a dictionary**. You have a list with other lists in it, which contain dictionaries.

Comment: @DerekEdwards is this helped you ?

Comment: Yep, just made yours the correct answer. Thanks!